# WIX Bootstrapper - Selected MSI packages uninstallation

Tags: wix, burn

I have created a Wix custom bootstrapper application and bundle file using Wix 3.8. Bundle file contains five MSI packages. Created a setup and installed it. All MSI packages are installed and uninstalled correctly.

Then, I have include "InstallCondition" attribute in each MSI package elements in bundle file. Installed the setup based on the selection (installed three MSI packages). Installation working fine.

Now I want to uninstall any of selected MSI packages from installed packages (three packages installed) using custom BA.

Is it possible do the above using Wix CBA? Please share any idea regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Plan` with the `Modify` action (or `Uninstall` if you want to uninstall the whole bundle).  Then in the `OnPlanPackageBegin` callback, set the desired state of the package (`Absent` to uninstall).  I think if the `InstallCondition` of a package evaluates to false during a `Modify` or `Uninstall` action, the engine would plan to uninstall it by default.